# Python OpenPyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with a large excel file(30MB+,xlsm). Many of them contain photos in cell comments, so this file takes up so much space. First im open a file to read and get specific column name. Im open that with:

```
self.wb = load_workbook(str(self.directory[0]), read_only=True, keep_vba=True, data_only=False)
self.ws = self.wb['BAZA_PRACOWNIKOW']
self.sheet = self.wb.active
```

After finding the appropriate cells, I open it again to add the relevant data to it:

```
self.wb = load_workbook(str(self.directory[0]), read_only=False, keep_vba=True, data_only=False)
self.ws = self.wb['BAZA_PRACOWNIKOW']
self.sheet = self.wb.active
```

When I complete this file I would like to save it, so:

```
self.wb.save('new.xlsm')
```

After that i got an error:

> D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py:310:
>   UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be
>   removed   warn(msg)
>   The file size after saving decrease to 8mb. All photos in comments are not in new.xlsm file.
>   Can someone help me ?

Comment: Could you provide an example .xlsm file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

> openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file
>   so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are
>   opened and saved with the same name.

Try lxlm or xlwings maybe?